# What is the most efficient way to broadcast an operation on slices of PyTorch Tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have a tensor T of shape (b, r)

I want to do an operation for each (r), in a way that it gets parallelized by the GPU

The naive implementation, in numpy for simplicity, would look something like:

```
T_dash = np.array([(T[i] - np.max(T[i]) for i in range(T.size[0])])
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Pytorch already does GPU calculations asynchronously. As long as you don't convert your tensors back to CPU tensors until after you have results for all the columns and you don't perform your calculations in place then it should automatically be done in parallel on the GPU. If you provide the specific operation that you want to perform faster and your current implementation then perhaps we could help more. If it's just subtracting the max of each row you could do `T - T.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)` where `T` is a tensor of shape `(b, r)`

Comment: I did not realize you could supply dimension arguments for max. That does solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Deleting my answer as it's not a real answer, but for posterity: After some more digging, I found this

torch.vmap

However it appears that it is not yet implemented in pytorch version 1.7.0, as on colab

module 'torch' has no attribute 'vmap'

Comment: ‍♂️ just reading the last comment now :D, anyway I'll leave the answer here until torch plans to drop this feature in the next stable.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new [vmap](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.vmap.html) function available (in the master branch at the time of writing, experimental) that will help do batch operations, where you define the operation to be performed for each element.

`vmap` can be helpful in **hiding batch dimensions**. In your case, it goes something like

```py
def each_elem_fn(tensor):
  return tensor - np.max(tensor)

torch.vmap(each_elem_fn)(batch_of_elems)
```

Note: As @jodag mentioned in the comment, for simply subtracting max you can use

```
T = T - T.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0]
```

however, if you want to generalize it to any custom function you shall use `vmap`.